# How do I get the id of an element from firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
//database
  database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  foods = database.getReference("Food/" + categoryID);
```

I need categoryID. How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. like this;

```
categoryID = getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryID");
foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");

database = FirebaseDataBase.getInstance();

foods = database.getReference("Food/" + categoryID + "/" + foodId);
```

with this method I could reach both food and category ID.

Answer (score 2):

To get the id, try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Food");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String keys=datas.getKey();
    }
  }
  @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     }
  });
```

The snapshot is at child `Food` then you can iterate inside the direct child and get the id which is `01`

Comment: Actually, I wanted to mean that reaching categoryID. When I changed "Food/01" or "Food/02" it works but it is working with just 01 or 02. I want /categoryID is changeable which one item is choosen. I have tried your methods but I didnt understand how I can use "keys".

Comment: the `keys` will retrieve 01 or 02.. keep the location at Food

Comment: didnt work. I have got error as null object reference. I was getting id from other class with intent methods. like that ;

  if (getIntent()!= null)
            _foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");
        if (!_foodId.isEmpty()) {
            getDetailFood(_foodId);
        }

I am able to reach and list menu and foodlist. But I cant see foodDetails. I have null object exception.